# iOS objective c perform selector not executing the method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

hey actually I used perform selector in a url request block and it was working fine at first but now it is not executing the function

the perform selector function is

```
       NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
        self.tmp=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"otp"] ;
        self.str=self.tmp;
        NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);
      //  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateStatus) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
    }] resume];
}
```

and the update status method is

```
-(void)updateStatus{
NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
[ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];
}
```

as it is not executing I am not able to perform segue and the app stays in the same page

Comment: delay second value is to small. Please increase it to 0.1 to 0.3 or plus

Comment: @Bilal yes update status is in the same class!!bt still it doesn't execute!!

Comment: @JitendraModi I was having 1.0 at first the same happened wen it was 1.0 delay

Comment: Are you calling this code from the main thread? All UI (including segues) have to be done on the main queue. (BTW, are you seeing your `NSLog` statements?)

Comment: @Rob this is actually in button action wen I am performing a url request I am doing this at the end of the url session!!

Comment: `URLSession` completion blocks don't run on the main thread. So, you'd generally dispatch this to the main queue,  if you haven't already..

Comment: @Rob.  nope I am not seeing anything in log statements but I had log before the perform selector and it prints bt this doesn't as it is not executed!!

Comment: @Rob I have to get the values from url request reply so I had to put inside session the value outside session doesn't nt wrk r print rite!!

Comment: @Rob I have updated is this enuf?

Comment: Closer. But I don't see you dispatching this code to the main queue, which you have to do when invoking UI changes from a `URLSession` completion handler. I'd use `dispatch_after` to the main queue, personally.

Comment: @Rob yes thanks I got it working!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple , update your UI in main thread

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
         });
```

**option 2**

or else create the simple method

```
       NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);
        [self updateStatus];
```

and call the method in Main thread

```
-(void)updateStatus{
NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];
});
}
```

**updated code**

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
       // NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
        //   NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
        self.tmp=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"otp"] ;
        self.str=self.tmp;
        NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmp);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
        });

    }] resume];
```

and call the method as

```
 -(void)updateStatus{
NSLog(@" storage:%@",self.str);
NSLog(@"tmp storage:%@",self.tmp);
[ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b1" sender:self];


}
```

Comment: where shud I use this??

Comment: yea let me try!!

Comment: Why use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`? Use `dispatch_after`.

Answer (score 0):

`performSelector` will not work if it's being called from background thread. Try this ...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`[self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];` dependent on `runloop`, and `background thread`'s `runloop` not turned on default.

so you should turn on the `runloop` or put the method to `main thread`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass in the relevant object that responds to the specified selector. Passing `nil` would send a message to nil and do nothing.
Assuming `updateStatus` method is declared in the same class where you call `performSelector`, you could do this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateStatus) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: yes method is in same view controller and still it is not executing that updatestatus block